# Server log in time is dependent on machine and user

Tags: unix, ssh, dns

I am attempting to ssh into a server and it takes a lot longer depending on the machine and user which I'm logging in from.  To describe that better,

```
userA@hostA~: ssh userA@hostB    # takes a long time
userA@hostA~: ssh userB@hostB    # takes an expected amount of time
userA@hostC~: ssh userA@hostB    # takes an expected amount of time
userB@hostA~: ssh userA@hostB    # takes an expected amount of time
```

I am in a local intranet with all machines running ubuntu 12.04.

Answer (score 0):

Delays are usually related to DNS problems (as you probably have already figured out). If it varies depending on different accounts for the same machine, you should look for any `from="pattern-list"` directives in the **authorized_keys** file that might cause extra DNS validations for one account.

But on the other hand it may just be as simple as `hostB` not being able to perform a reverse-DNS for the ip address of `hostA` on the first connection attempt, but then the negative result is cached for some (relatively short) time in the local DNS server making subsequent connections go through quickly.

You could try adding the ip-address and name of hostA to the `/etc/hosts` file on hostB:

```
10.0.0.42           hostA
```